# Data into excel file in a particular format

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am getting the data from Sql Server  like

[image]

for about 1000 stores.

I need to put data in to excel file like as

[image]

and so on until now i have managed to code like as console application

```
if (reader.HasRows) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("StoresWithProduct", connection);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreID", reader.GetInt32(0));
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "table1");
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in ds.Tables["table1"].Rows) {
            Console.Write("Store Code:" + dr1["StoreCode"] + "\t");
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["table1"].Rows)
            {
                Console.Write(dr["itemNumber"]+"-" + dr["quantity"]+"\t\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
}
Console.ReadLine();
reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

but not able to put into the excel file the way i want, any pointer will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you output for excel, you're probably better off going for some CSV (comma separated variables)

Comment: so its not possible the way i want?

Comment: well, to be honest, I'm not *sure* of what is "the way you want"

Comment: @emartel i have updated the question please check, any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: was any of the provided answers sufficient or you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

We've used this library extensively for generating complex Excel workbooks including pivot tables. Usage is very straightforward with plenty of examples and help on codeplex site.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work if you wrote the output to a text file. Using CSV ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) you can easily export your data to Excel. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard), due to the lack of standard, using `tabs` like you do should work.

You simply need to output the data row by row, using a separator (usually `,`, `;` or `tab`) and use a `new line` to define a new row.

Excel supports CSV files as `Text Files`. I don't have Excel on this PC, but usually there's an import wizard to help you with the creation of columns.